# .mdf and .ldf files showing wrong dates?

Tags: sql-server

Sorry I am asking a question related to another post(How to add loop of .bak files to restore in single sscript?) where I can not able to add a comment.

Based on script posted in question (How to add loop of .bak files to restore in single sscript?) I have restored .bak files and put .mdf and .ldf files in folder. I have completed restoring on Friday 9th sep 2016 but when I checked this morning .mdf and .ldf have date 10th sep 2016. why the date is showing as 10 sep 2016 instead of 9th sep 2016? please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826789/what-is-the-ldf-file-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826789/what-is-the-ldf-file-in-sql-server), the LDF file contains the transaction logs from your database.  So if any activity occurred on 10th Sep 2016, the LDF file would have been updated with that timestamp.

Assuming the underlying data or state of that database file changed, them the MDF file would also have been updated (q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175882/what-is-an-mdf-file)).

Comment: Thanks. does this means do I need to truncate log file? and also four backups log files have same size and two backup log files have same size? are these size differences are correct? please let me know.