# ldf in simple mode grew

Tags: sql-server, logging, ldf

The next .ldf grew to 50GB, and is eating all the disk… (it is in SIMPLE recovery model)
[image]

I wanted to be able to roughly answer these questions:

-what’s inside the .ldf? (can I say it is just temp tables?!)
-which command or user caused this 50GB to fill up?
-potential issues if I force to shrink the file to 10GB.

I do not want this information to blame anyone, but to educate ourselves on the usage.

Amazingly I get this result:
[image]

Comment: Have you read this already?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826789/what-is-the-ldf-file-in-sql-server

Comment: Yes, I know what .ldf is; this case is a 50GB filled up log, from a db with simple RM. When I ask what's inside, I wanted to literally retrieve the name of the temp tables that are inside; or know what is inside.

Comment: 50GB sounds pretty massive to me.  How large are the tables in your database?

Comment: the .mdf is  1.78GB

Comment: As you said that "Column 'log_reuse_wait_desc' = LOG_BACKUP", then it's 100% certain it's not in simple recovery.

Comment: I edited the post; why do I get that result?!

Comment: Because the database is NOT in simple recovery.

Comment: sys.database says that in fact is. I attached the screenshot

Comment: OK, my appologies. You probably bumped into this bug: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2830400.

Answer (score 0):

Check for uncommitted Transactions by running the below script:

```
SELECT 
er.session_id
,er.open_transaction_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er
```

you can use sp_who2 to track down the user.

If you urgently need to free-up space in the Log file - without performing a shrink - take a log-backup.